# Where's Wahlberg?

Tags: visual, knowledge

### Can you find the famous faces in this crowd?

[image]

(click to enlarge)

### Two of these are in profile, the rest are facing the camera, though their eyes are not always focused ***on*** the camera.

(All images were found through Google search with "Labeled for reuse with modification" licensing, like [this](https://www.google.com/search?biw=911&bih=449&tbs=sur%3Afmc%2Cisz%3Am&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=kDT4WobMKufm5gKwr7fQCw&q=stack+exchange&chrome_dont_add_custom_search_engines_srsly=&oq=stack+exchange&gs_l=img.3..0i67k1j0l3j0i24k1l6.20391.20391.0.21896.1.1.0.0.0.0.91.91.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.1.90....0.QTQjLwFNRQI#imgrc=STgCDPFIkP8rgM:).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> From L-R(ish)
>  
>  1. Betty White ([Credit to Nick A](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65739/wheres-wahlberg#comment198752_65741)) *<del>Barbara Bush</del>*
>  
>  2. kevin smith ([Credit to ManyPinkHats](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65739/wheres-wahlberg/65741?noredirect=1#comment198760_65741)) 
>  3. Donald Trump
>  4. Barrack Obama
>  5. **Mark Wahlberg** (yellow)
>  
>  6. Steve Buscemi
>  7. Groucho Marx ([Credit to Herb Wolfe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65739/wheres-wahlberg/65741?noredirect=1#comment198758_65741)) *<del>Stalin</del>*
>  8. Rosie O'Donnell (Thanks for the hint Chowzen and [credit to kedarguru](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65739/wheres-wahlberg/65741?noredirect=1#comment198766_65741))
>  
>  [image]

Comment: I know those 2 faces but I don’t know how to tell you without spoiling it in the comments...

Comment: @kedarguru [rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)

Comment: @kedarguru Do you know the one that he has listed first? (not rot13 Oneonen Ohfu)

Comment: You got the face, but the name isn't rot13 Oneonen Ohfu...

Comment: (to be fair, these are probably hard to ID due to pixelation...)

Comment: @Chowzen Number 1 looks like rot 13 Orggl Juvgr

Comment: @NickA Yes to Orggl Juvgr.

Comment: No to the Russian dictator (though the correct answer shares his last name with *another* famous Russian!) No to Michelle Wolf.

Comment: #7 is Tebhpub Znek

Comment: @HerbWolfe Yep, that's him alright. Thanks!

Comment: Is #2 [rot-13 xriva fzvgu](http://decode.org/?q=xriva+fzvgu)?

Comment: #8 is rot13(znqbaan'f orfg sevraq va "n yrnthr bs gurve bja")

Comment: #8 is Ebfvr B'Qbaaryy

Comment: I just wanted to suggest a contrasting outline so that the circles are better defined and don't blend with the crowd so much https://imgur.com/gallery/0VMxO btw jpeg doesn't like the color red and messes it up in a bad way. Compare the image in this post and a freshly-made png with the same red circles drawn in paint. So you'd want to either use png if you want better definition or pick a different color.

Comment: @user1306322 how's it now?

Comment: @WELZ the yellow circle looks the best :D

Answer (score 24):

Sorry, I don't know how to do these puzzles the normal way, so I clicked the link you so generously provided in your question, and I typed "crowd" instead of "stack exchange" in the search query. Found the source image you used to create this puzzle in the first row, put it in Photoshop and overlaid with yours with a "difference" filter. There is a vague outline due to JPEG compression and resizing variations, but the edited faces are pretty visible.

Seems like you've messed something up with the lower right person's face while editing :p

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

These stood out for me, mainly because they do not 'match' with their surroundings:

> [image]
>
>  From the eight faces, I only recognize Donald Trump, though.

<sub>apologies for using *blue* freehand circles, but red ones aren't really visible on this picture</sub>

Comment: Interesting! The only one you missed was the only one that was clued (in the title).

Comment: I think I found him now as well.

Comment: There's life [outside of PuzzlingStackExchange](http://ew.com/), you know... :)

Answer (score 2):

> [image: answer]
>
>
>  1. ?
>  
>  2. ?
>  
>  3. Trump
>  
>  4. Obama
>  
>  5. Mark Wahlberg
>  
>  6. ?
>  
>  7. ?
>  
>  8. ?

Comment: Your visual markings are nearly as hard to see as the originals :c)